# Room : error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type

Tags: android, android-room

Below query can generate multiple data that's why I took List as a return type and also I tested with SQLite browser query working fine but still I am getting this error

```
 @Query("select e.entradaid from encounters e join jobs j on e.id = j.encounterid " +
            "where " + "strftime('%Y-%m-%d',e.appointmentdate) = :appointmentDate")
    List<String> getEncounterIdsByAppointmentDate(String appointmentDate);
```

Comment: What kind of error?